# Selenium EC.element_to_be_clickable still returns stale element error

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I am not sure what is wrong with this. Am I using `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` right? I am getting the error message: "`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`". I am pretty sure the XPATH is valid and have even tried with another that designates the same element.

**My code:**

```
driver.get("https://browzine.com/libraries/1374/subjects")
parent_url = "https://browzine.com/libraries/1374/subjects"
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

subjects_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='subjects-list-subject-name']")
subjects = 0
for sub in subjects_avail:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, "//span[@class='subjects-list-subject-name']")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(sub).click(sub).perform()
    subjects = +1
    driver.get(parent_url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you clicking the `sub` element the driver is navigating to the new page.
Then you are opening the main page again with

```py
driver.get(parent_url)
```

But all the web elements in `subjects_avail` list became Stale since driver already left the original main page.
To make your code working you have to get the `subjects_avail` list again each time you getting back to the main page and then select the correct sub title element.
Something like this:

```py
url = "https://browzine.com/libraries/1374/subjects"
subj_list_xpath = "//span[@class='subjects-list-subject-name']"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

subjects_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, subj_list_xpath)

for i in range(len(subjects_avail)):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, subj_list_xpath)))
    subjects_avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, subj_list_xpath)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(subjects_avail[i]).click(subjects_avail[i]).perform()
    driver.get(url)
```